# How can I get TypeScript to load the PDF.js NPM module and @types bindings in a way that generates working Node.JS code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module, pdf.js

**Context**

I'm trying to import [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) into a TypeScript project. I'm using the DefinitelyTyped [bindings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfjs-dist) for [`pdfjs-dist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist), installed via `npm install @types/pdfjs-dist` and `npm install pdfjs-dist`.

**Problem**

I can't seem to get TypeScript to compile my project. I'm using  source code copied straight from the tests on DefinitelyTyped. This is the simplified (deletions only) code I'm trying to compile (an exact copy of the test code from DefinitelyTyped also fails in the same way):

```
import { PDFJSStatic } from 'pdfjs-dist';
var PDFJS: PDFJSStatic;
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(console.log);
```

TypeScript finds the type declarations module, and considers the import of `PDFJSStatic` to be valid. It doesn't think `PDFJS` is ever initialized, but if I turn off `strict` in `tsconfig`, the code compiles, but it compiles to:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var PDFJS;
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(console.log);
```

Which obviously doesn't work. It's not compiling the `import` statement into anything.

**Question**

How can I import PDF.JS into a TypeScript project and compile it into working Node.JS code via the declaration files in `@types/pdfjs-dist`?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried different variations on `import`, to no avail. Switching to `require` also doesn't seem to help.

I've verified that the `pdjs-dist` dependency, and the `@types/pdfjs-dist` dependencies are present, updated, and usable directly from NodeJS (non-TypeScript programs).

I've tried various values for `module` in my tsconfig. They change the generated code sometimes, but none of them change it to contain the needed import.

I've tried adding `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/pdfjs-dist/index.d.ts" />` above the `import` line. That didn't change the behavior.

**Environment**

`tsc` version 2.4.2, node 8.5, and `npm` 5.3. I have the following `tsconfig.json` in my project root:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs":true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
     "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "dist/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Azoson's answer is a good workaround for the broken-ish typings. If I have some free time soon I will try to submit a patch to the PDFJS library to resolve this issue. I am not an expert at either this library or TypeScript though, so that may prove difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you can use `require` function.

Add `@types/node` packages, and write `require('pdfjs-dist')` at the top of the your source code.
So, you can modify your code like below.

Now, this code will work.

```
import { PDFJSStatic } from 'pdfjs-dist';
const PDFJS: PDFJSStatic = require('pdfjs-dist');
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(console.log);
```

I think that `@types/pdfjs-dist` has problems in its implementation.

Comment: Now, this method does not work.
Please see this change of `@types/node` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/41e178d963a2e55106e20f423fd7f311e8632861#diff-21e9d6e91ee2c9204daebf0a94339b21

Comment: Now, this code will work.

    import { PDFJSStatic } from 'pdfjs-dist';
    const PDFJS: PDFJSStatic = require('pdfjs-dist');
    PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(console.log);

I think that `@types/pdfjs-dist` has problems in its implementation.

Answer (score 5):

With `@types/pdfjs-dist` 2.1.0 and `pdfjs-dist` "2.1.266", the fundamental issue still doesn't quite seem fixed, but I've found that the approach from [their own test](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfjs-dist/pdfjs-dist-tests.ts) works:

```js
import { getDocument, PDFDocumentProxy, PDFPromise, Util } from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

(It's not pretty, though, as it pollutes your namespace.)

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried different ways. For me, the most readable was this one:

```
import * as pdfjslib from 'pdfjs-dist';
let PDFJS = pdfjslib.PDFJS;
PDFJS.disableTextLayer = true;
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```

Comment: This does not work. I get `cannot use namespace 'pdfjslib' as a value.`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, without having to use `require`:

```
import * as pdfjslib from "pdfjs-dist";
const PDFJS = (<any>pdfjslib) as PDFJSStatic;
```

You just have to silence the type errors by casting the module to `any`.

The typings in @types/pdfjs-dist are definitely incorrect, but this should be a quick workaround. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using React you can use `react-pdf` package which uses `pdfjs` under the hood. It also has it's own typings so you can import this without needing `require`.

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a rubberband solution. Was tired of getting errors spread across multiple components and moved the pdfjslib to a single one. Now my other components refer to this one without errors, and only that component shows errors on import.

```
export { PDFDocumentLoadingTask, PDFDocumentProxy, 
PDFPageProxy, getDocument } from 'pdfjs-dist';
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
(pdfjsLib as any).GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.8.162/pdf.worker.js`;
export { pdfjsLib };
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked great! Few notes since this was posted: Use https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdf.js to get the CDN libraries available to match with your installed NPM of pdfjs-dist. At the time of this comment 4.x is not supported for this solution since no CDN is available so I went back to the latest 3.x version.

Answer (score 0):

The following works.

- pdfjs-dist v3.5.141
- typescript v3.9.10

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'

...

    // in this example, data is a Uint8Array
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data }).promise
    for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdf.numPages; pageNum++) {
      const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum)
      ...
```

Also it doesn't hurt to have a file, "pdfjs-dist.d.ts":

```
declare module 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'
```